# ffprobe can not read a file generated by node JS createWriteStream() on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, ffmpeg, promise

I have a setup running on AWS that triggers an AWS Lambda function when a video file is uploaded to an S3 bucket. The Lambda function is written in node and downloads the file, streams it to a temp working file and then executes ffprobe on it followed by an ffmpeg command.

ffprobe throws the following error:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x4ea8e20] error reading header download: Invalid data found when processing input
```

The bug is hard to reproduce and occurs only half the time, which I believe to be because of the async nature of the program.

My main function is as follows

```
downloadFile(library.getDownloadStream, logger, sourceLocation, localFilePath)
        .then(() => ffprobe(logger))
        .then(() => ffmpeg(logger, keyPrefix))
        .then(() => removeDownload(logger, localFilePath))
        .then(() => uploadFiles(library.uploadToBucket, logger, keyPrefix))
        .then(data => invocation.callback())
        .catch(error => invocation.callback(error));
```

The ffprobe Function:

```
function downloadFile(downloadFunc, logger, sourceLocation, download) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        logger.log(`Starting download: ${sourceLocation.bucket} / ${sourceLocation.key}`);

        var downloadFile = createWriteStream(download);

        downloadFunc(sourceLocation.bucket, sourceLocation.key)
            .on('end', () => {
                logger.log("closing writing stream");
                downloadFile.end();

                logger.log('Download finished');

                resolve();
            })
            .on('error', reject)
            .pipe(downloadFile);
    });
}
```

Each build/update uploads the latest ffmpeg version to AWS. I can not reproduce this error locally.

Why is ffprobe throwing this error regarding the header?

**Update**

Logging the downloaded file's filesize prints *exactly* the same amount of bytes, regardless of wether ffprobe is successful or not.

However, when I set a timeOut before resolving the promise, the bug no longer occurs and ffprobe runs successfully each time:

```
downloadFunc(sourceLocation.bucket, sourceLocation.key)
        .on('end', () => {

            logger.log('Download finished');

            // Filesize
            var meta = fs.statSync(download);
            var fileSizeInBytes = meta["size"];

            logger.log(fileSizeInBytes);

            // resolve();
            setTimeout(resolve, 1000); 
        })
        .on('error', reject)
        .pipe(downloadFile);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: what u have not clear regarding 'finished' event from downloadfile and in what form the promise returned by downloadfile includes a ref to the media  for use by the next promise (ffprobe)... FWIW in node/heroku, i have had good luck with promise chain doing media downloads -> then.(ffmpeg functions) outputting tmp files for the fs implentation to handle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need downloadfile.end if you are piping to it. Maybe that's the problem.  Does the end event happen after it is done writing to the pipe? Maybe a tiny delay before resolving.  You could also check the file length on server manually next time to debug and see if it wrote all of it.

Comment: I added the end() statement because I thought the issue was caused by not closing it, to no avail. I'll try checking the filesize manually. Due to the bug occurring on only half of the requests, I think it's caused by the download not having properly finished?

Comment: I updated my original question according to the things you recommended. I'm baffled.